# React hook with constant input parameter - hook creator?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Since React hooks rely on the execution order one should generally not use hooks inside of loops. I ran into a couple of situations where I have a constant input to the hook and thus there should be no problem. The only thing I'm wondering about is how to enforce the input to be constant.

Following is a simplified example:

```js
const useHookWithConstantInput = (constantIdArray) => {
  const initialState = buildInitialState(constantIdArray);
  const [state, changeState] = useState(initialState);

  const callbacks = constantIdArray.map((id) => useCallback(() => {
    const newState = buildNewState(id, constantIdArray);
    changeState(newState);
  }));

  return { state, callbacks };
}
```

```js
const idArray = ['id-1', 'id-2', 'id-3'];

const SomeComponent = () => {
  const { state, callbacks } = useHookWithConstantInput(idArray);

  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={callbacks[0]}>
        {state[0]}
      </div>

      <div onClick={callbacks[1]}>
        {state[1]}
      </div>

      <div onClick={callbacks[2]}>
        {state[2]}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Is there a pattern for how to enforce the `constantIdArray` not to change? My idea would be to use a creator function for the hook like this:

```js
const createUseHookWithConstantInput = (constantIdArray) => () => {
  ...
}

const idArray = ['id-1', 'id-2', 'id-3'];

const useHookWithConstantInput = createUseHookWithConstantInput(idArray)

const SomeComponent = () => {
  const { state, callbacks } = useHookWithConstantInput();

  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

How do you solve situations like this?

Comment: There is no need for you to provide checks for same input.For instance you may check that `useState` doesn't perform any validation on what input is provided. It just defines a standard that the input value will be used only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `useEffect` with an empty dependency list so it will only run once. Inside this you could set your callbacks and afterwards they will never change because the `useEffect` will not run again. That would look like the following:

```
const useHookWithConstantInput = (constantIdArray) => {
  const [state, changeState] = useState({});
  const [callbacks, setCallbacks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    changeState(buildInitialState(constantIdArray));
    const callbacksArray = constantIdArray.map((id) => {
        const newState = buildNewState(id, constantIdArray);
        changeState(newState);
    });

    setCallbacks(callbacksArray);
  }, []);

  return { state, callbacks };
}
```

Although this will set two states the first time it runs instead of giving them initial values, I would argue it's better than building the state and creating new callbacks everytime the hook is run.

If you don't like this route, you could alternatively just create a state like so `const [constArray, setConstArray] = useState(constantIdArray);` and because the parameter given to `useState` is only used as a default value, it'll never change even if `constantIdArray` changes. Then you'll just have to use `constArray` in the rest of the hook to make sure it'll always only be the initial value.

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks. Another solution going in this direction might be to use `useMemo` like this:`const constantIdArray = useMemo(() => idArray, [])`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to go for would be with `useMemo`. This is what I ended up implementing.

```js
const createCallback = (id, changeState) => () => {
  const newState = buildNewState(id, constantIdArray);
  changeState(newState);
};

const useHookWithConstantInput = (constantIdArray) => {
  const initialState = buildInitialState(constantIdArray);
  const [state, changeState] = useState(initialState);

  const callbacks = useMemo(() =>
    constantIdArray.map((id) => createCallback(id, changeState)),
    [],
  );

  return { state, callbacks };
};
```